# Write serial port : invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Tags: qt

I would like to send data between `Qt` and a µC via serial port COM.

I am trying to send a char but when I use `serial->write(250)`, I get this error:

> invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*

But if I do `serial->write("A")`, it works. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could you show some of your code? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you say "write 250", what do you mean? Do you want to send the string `"250"`, or the string `"\xFA"` consisting of a single byte having value 250?

Comment: No I want to send 250 in decimal 0xFA in hex

Answer (score 0):

250 is interpret by the compiler as of type `int`, and the `serial->write()`-functions requires a `const char *` as input;
If you want to send `250` as a char, you have to convert the type:

```
char cValue = 250;
char *pCValue = &cValue;
serial->write(pCValue);
```

However, please note that `pCValue` is a pointer to the temporary char and will only be valid while c is in scope. I guess you also need to add a null terminator at the end of the array if you can't specify the data size in the serial-class, as pointed out by owacoder.

Comment: Thank you but that's annoying what if I have lot of value to send?
I can't use a cast?

Comment: Create a char array, example with 5 values: char values[] = {150, 200, 100, 100, 100} (or preferably use std::array) or std::vector<char> if the size is not fixed (and pass vector's data()-function to the write function)

Comment: thank you so if i do
serial->write( values);
How can I choose values[3]?

Comment: @A.Fagrell - "250 is interpret by the compiler as of type int, and the serial->write()-functions requires a const char * as input" - It also requires that the `const char *` be nul-terminated, which your code doesn't do.

Comment: @owacoder either that or it's possible to specify a size in the serial-class. Don't know the requirements.

Comment: But i just want to send constant through the serial!

Answer (score 0):

The members available on QSerialPort for write data are this from [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport-members.html):

```
write(const char *, qint64 ) : qint64
write(const char *) : qint64
write(const QByteArray &) : qint64
writeData(const char *, qint64 ) : qint64
writeData(const char *, qint64 ) : qint64
```

If you use `serial->write(250)` the compile cast the number to an int and threre is no member for manage an int. Instead if you use `serial->write("A")` the "A" can be cast to `char *`.

For send a lot of byte you can use QByteArray:

```
QByteArray cmd;
cmd.append('A');
cmd.append('B');
cmd.append('C');
serial -> write (cmd);
```

This way send all characters and there is a lot of usefull Qt class that can convert an object to a QByteArray; for example a QString is simply converto to QByteArray like this:

```
QString str = "ABC";
QByteArray cmd = str.toLatin1();
serial -> write (cmd);
```